# How to change color of selected item from Multiselect ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view as :

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />
```

In corresponding activity i have set elements in listview as

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, phoneContactList));
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

in above code , `phoneContactList` is an arrayList.

Onclick of item from list, how can change it's color?

Thank You.

Comment: [See here...](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-read-contact-and-display-in.html)

Comment: you will get position of selected item on onItemClickListener,through this you can change color

Answer (score 0):

just foind this page: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=454 helped me a lot